# persistence of objects in python

Tags: python, oop, wxpython

Till now I have done only procedural programming in C so I am rather unclear about both OOP and Python.

I have a large project which contains a number of python files.
File a.py defines a class called fobject
I am using python 2.5

File b.py and c.py have classes called BProject and CProject which have an object of fobject as parameter.
I have included using import CProject (defined in c.py) in b.py.
I have a list in  CProject which I fill using wx python GUI.
Next I call a function BRun defined in BProject which internally calls a CRun Function in CProject ie. in c.py.

In this CRun I want to manipulate the list but list is always empty at this time. Why is this so?

What should I do given the constraint is I can't change anything a.py in which fobject is defined ?

## file : c.py

```
def Instance(fObject):
    return test_page_CProject(fObject)


class CProject(object):

    def __init__(self, fObject):
        self.fObj = fObject
        self.IntList  =  []
        ##snip


    def  OnIntSelectBtnPress(self,parent):
        print ":self.IntList"
        print self.IntList
        self.listBoxIntSelect.InsertItems(self.IntList,0)
        print self.IntList


    def OnIntRun(self):

                IntLModeList = self.IntListIntMode
                #snip
```

## file b.py

```
def Instance(fObject):
    return BProject(fObject)

class BProject(object):

    def __init__(self, fObject):

        self.FObj = fObject
        #snip
        Object = __import__('CProject')
        #snip

        self.intObject = Object.Instance(self.FObj)
        self.intObject.OnIntRun()
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: This question is so confused that it is currently basically impossible to answer. Showing the code would help.

Comment: kindly post the relevant code as well to understand the problem.

Comment: I have added code to make my question clearer

Answer (score 3):

You don't understand python. You need to understand *variables* (almost everything in python is basically a pointer), and *namespaces*.

OK, so you don't understand when python creates new objects.

In 90% of cases, every time you see an object, it will be a new one.

For example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a + [4,5] 
print a
>>> [1,2,3]
```

See? b is a new object, a is untouched.

Also:

```
def func(a):
    a = [1,2,3]+a 
    return a

a = [4,5]
print func(a)
>>> [1,2,3,4,5]
print a
>>> [4,5]
```

Why did this happen? Inside the function, there's a whole new namespace (which is probably something like a new stack). So the new `a` inside the function has nothing to do with the old `a` outside the function.

It's really hard to make python share data, which makes it really hard for one section of code to mess with variables in another area.

You *can* alter stuff, but you have to jump through hoops:

```
def func(a):
    a.append([4,5])
    return a

a = [1,2,3]
print func(a)
>>> [1,2,3,4,5]
print a
>>> [1,2,3,4,5]
```

See, it worked! I altered `a`, because I used a method of a, not creating a new variable.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say but it is not fully related to my question