# sharing variables between two wxpython tabs

Tags: python, oop, wxpython

I have asked this question but it was not very well formulated.

[persistence of objects in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420688/persistence-of-objects-in-python)

As a newbie to both python, and GUI programming

I have a large project which contains a number of python files. File a.py defines a class called fobject I am using python 2.5

File b.py and c.py have classes called BProject and CProject which have an object of fobject as parameter. These are pages in wx python based program.

I have included using import CProject (defined in c.py) in b.py. I have a list in CProject which I fill using wx python GUI. Next I call a function BRun defined in BProject which internally calls a CRun Function in CProject ie. in c.py.

In this CRun I want to manipulate the list but list is always empty at this time. Why is this so?

What should I do given the constraint is I can't change anything a.py in which fobject is defined ?

**file : c.py**

```
def Instance(fObject):
    return test_page_CProject(fObject)


class CProject(object):

    def __init__(self, fObject):
        self.fObj = fObject
        self.IntList  =  []
        ##snip

    def  OnIntSelectBtnPress(self,parent):
        print ":self.IntList"
        print self.IntList
        self.listBoxIntSelect.InsertItems(self.IntList,0)
        print self.IntList

    def OnIntRun(self):
        IntLModeList = self.IntListIntMode
        #snip
```

**file b.py**

```
def Instance(fObject):
    return BProject(fObject)

class BProject(object):

    def __init__(self, fObject):
        self.FObj = fObject
        #snip
        Object = __import__('CProject')
        #snip

        self.intObject = Object.Instance(self.FObj)
        self.intObject.OnIntRun()
```

When CPython.OnIntRun is called the self.IntList is empty when it should'nt be

Answer (score 1):

I'm not following this very well, but normally you need to pass the data in when you instantiate the class. Otherwise, you can use PubSub to pass the information between classes or you could create a simple local web server that each tab checks periodically for new data and updates itself.

Comment: I believe creating a webserver would be a over kill for this application. This application needs to beinstalled individually over many PCs even without network access and also on the customer end to exercise our h/w. This application interacts with our board.

Comment: You would create the server in memory using Python's socket module, SimpleHTTPServer or SimpleXMLRPCServer. I'm not talking about loading apache or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

If your fObject maintains the references to bProject and cProject, couldn't you write a `send_to_c(msg)` function in your fObject, that you could call from your bProject (and vice versa)?

Comment: Unfortunately since fObject defined in a.py and is common to many platforms and hence I cannot modify it.

Comment: so create a `class gObject(fObject)` (inherits from fObject) and add your functions to gObject!